# How to install 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries 4.0.0-beta3' on Xamarin PCL?

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

Following [this](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Tip-Calc---The-Core-Project) tutorial I'm trying to install MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries in Core project. The latest version of this library 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries 4.0.0-beta3'.
After adding Nuget Package I have the following error:

> Could not install package 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries 4.0.0-beta3'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile14', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to original question:

MvvmCross is not available for ASP.NET. You need to use it in one of the compatible frameworks like UWP, Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS or a PCL.

Updated Question:

MvvmCross uses at least .NET 4.5 with profile 259. Switch to those to be able to install the libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but where I must change it?
Now I have following properties
[link](http://dl2.joxi.net/drive/0010/1041/656401/150915/59f6d31d2d.jpg)

Comment: You need to click on "Change" there. Then select: .NET 4.5, Windows 8, Windows Phone 8.1, Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.iOS clasic. You can check the result in your Core.csproj file under `TargetFrameworkProfile`